# How to use dynamic object properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface, typescript2.0

I'm working with TypeScript and I need to deal with dynamic object properties. I wish that I could be a master in TypeScript but I am not. The problem I have is that in my current project, I would like to give users the possibility to input their own custom interface to a Generic interface.

What I got working now is the following interface

```
export interface Filter {
  columnId: string;
  searchTerm: string;
}
export interface GridState {
  filters: Filter[];
}

// use it as an array of filters
const state: GridState = {
  filters: [{ columnId: 'firtName', searchTerm: 'John' }]
}
```

However from what is shown above, I would like to give the user the possibility to use his own interface. So let say that instead of `columnId`, he wants to use `field` and instead of `searchTerm` he would use `value`. So his custom interface would be

```
export interface CustomFilter {
  field: string;
  value: string;
}
```

What I would like to provide to the user is something like this, a custom structure template

```
export interface FilterStruct {
  propNameColumnId: string;
  propNameSearchTerm: string;
}
```

but how do I connect the 2 together? How do I use the user's `CustomFilter` with the `FilterStruct`. The following doesn't work and I know it's not correct.

```
export interface GridState {
  filters: FilterStruct<CustomFilter>[];
}
```

The end goal is that the user would be able to input with his own interface and his own property names. Then on my side, I would just loop through the array with the dynamic object property that was provided.

Comment: When you say "users the possibility to input their own custom interface", do you mean given them that possibility at run time?

Comment: ah sorry, I meant in their code since they would want to create their own interface, not at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `GridState` generic and provide a default value for the generic parameter. Also `FilterStruct` can inherit `Array`, so we can add extra properties to the array, using a helper function :

```
export interface FilterStruct<T> extends Array<T> {
    // We make sure the property names are actually properties of T
    // We make these optional you should use default values if they are undefined 
    // We do this to keep initialization simple in the non customized scenario, you can make them mandatory, but then you can't initialize with a simple array
    propNameColumnId?: keyof T; 
    propNameSearchTerm?: keyof T;
}
export interface Filter {
    columnId: string;
    searchTerm: string;
}
export interface CustomFilter {
    field: string;
    value: string;
}
// T has a default value of Filter so we don't have to specify it, unless we want to customize
export interface GridState<T = Filter> {
    filters: FilterStruct<T>;
}
// Helper function to create an array with the extra properties
function createFilterStruct<T>(cfg: { propNameColumnId: keyof T; propNameSearchTerm: keyof T; }, items: T[]) {
    return Object.assign(items, cfg);
}

// Default we can use simple array initailization
const state: GridState = {
    filters: [{ columnId: 'firtName', searchTerm: 'John' }]
}

// Custom filter, create with createFilterStruct
const stateCustom: GridState<CustomFilter> = {
    filters: createFilterStruct({ propNameColumnId: 'value', propNameSearchTerm: 'field' }, [
        { value: 'firtName', field: 'John' }
    ])
}

//Usage
function loopThrough<T>(grid: GridState<T>){
    // Provide defaults for propNameColumnId and propNameSearchTerm
    let propNameColumnId = grid.filters.propNameColumnId || 'columnId' as keyof T
    let propNameSearchTerm = grid.filters.propNameSearchTerm || 'searchTerm' as keyof T

    // Loop throught the array normally, it is just an array
    for(let filter of grid.filters){
        // Access the properties
        console.log(`${filter[propNameColumnId]} = ${filter[propNameSearchTerm]}`);
    }
}

loopThrough(stateCustom);
loopThrough(state);
```

Comment: wow I would have never find this out on my own. This is a different than I anticipated, now I'm a bit confused on how will I loop through this in my code then? Do I have to do some kind of `instanceof` to figure out when it uses the `CustomFilter` or not? Would you mind giving an example on how to loop through that, considering that it could be with/without a `CustomFilter`, it would help a lot.

Comment: @ghiscoding Added usage example, `filters` is just an array, things work as they normally do, it just has some extra properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, TypeScript is great and I wanted to make sure to use it properly :)